# Order a variable and separate by another variable R

Tags: r

I want to order() a variable by the number of characters it has and then separate that variable based on gender, f and m. How can I do that using R?

Comment: `x[order(nchar(x))]` will order `x` by the number of characters. I have no idea what you mean by "separate based on gender". Please add a little bit of sample data (use `dput()` for copy/pasteable sample data which will make answering easy), and also show the desired output for the sample input.

Comment: I would like to order separately for each gender the x[order(nchar(x))].

Comment: Okay. Please add a little bit of sample data (use `dput()` for copy/pasteable sample data which will make answering easy), and also show the desired output for the sample input

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm not sure I understand how to use dput (). I attempted by it did not work. Largest_words <- order(char(pollogames))[1:5]. Now I get my results from this, but would like to separate it bases on gender.

Comment: If `pollogames` is a data frame, run the command `dput(droplevels(pollogames[1:10, ]))` to get a copy/pasteable version of the first 10 rows of your data. Edit that into your question. If all 10 of those rows have the same gender, you might need a different subset, like `dput(droplevels(pollogames[c(1:5, 101:105), ]))`. Just pick a few M rows and a few F rows.

Comment: ...if you have a lot of columns that aren't relevant for the question, you can pick out specific columns too, like `dput(droplevels(pollogames[c(1:5, 101:105),c("column1", "gender") ]))` to share those rows of only columns named "column1" and "gender".

Comment: Show in New WindowClear OutputExpand/Collapse Output
structure(list(name = structure(1:5, .Label = c("Alex Josh Adams", 
"Alex Berniugn", "Abbigol Alexander", "Potter Allbinore", "Aaron Poss"), class = "factor"), 
    sex = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("female", 
    "male"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling your data `d`,

```
d[order(d$sex, nchar(as.character(d$name))), ]
#                name    sex
# 2     Alex Berniugn female
# 5        Aaron Poss   male
# 1   Alex Josh Adams   male
# 4  Potter Allbinore   male
# 3 Abbigol Alexander   male
```

Comment: This allowed me to calculate the male gender characters. How do I calculate the female?

Comment: This does both, it sorts first by sex, and then within sex it sorts by number of characters in the name. If you want to sort by characters first and then by sex, just switch the order of the arguments, `d[order(nchar(as.character(d$name)), d$sex), ]`